# Browser notifications decidable actions not working (javascript, vue.js) - is it no longer supported?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, notifications

Although I'm using a package called [vue-native-notification](https://github.com/dennisbruner/vue-native-notification) it should work mostly the same as regular native notifications. I would like to add actions to my notification for e.g.: Someone is calling you -> answer / decline

The problem is, whenever I add the actions, my notification stops working without any errors in the console, it just doesn't show up. As soon as I delete the actions property, everything works fine again.

Is there any problem with my code?

```
this.$notification.show('Call', {
    body: 'Someone is calling you',
    icon: 'https://test.com/public/images/logo.png',
    image: 'https://test.com/public/images/logo.png',
    badge: 'https://test.com/public/images/logo.png',
    actions: [
      {
        action: 'answer',
        title: 'Answer'
      },
      {
        action: 'decline', 
        title: 'Decline'
      }
   ]
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the browser, which one are you testing this with?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/actions

[image: BrowserCompat]

Comment: But I have to say, I'm not much further than you with this, ran into the same issue (which is why I found this post) and the above is one of the very few resources around that topic...

Comment: I tried on chrome 85 when I asked so it should work if it is still supported

Comment: I do have the same problem. Chrome 86.

Comment: Is this API deprecated? Because i can't get it to work either